# Rcpp with OpenMP critical directive significatnly slower than compiled C++ code

Tags: c++, r, openmp, rcpp

As the title says, using `#pragma omp critical` directive in R package with Rcpp significantly slows execution in comparison to compiled & run C++ code used in R package due to not using all CPU power.

Consider a simple C++ program (with cmake):

test.h as:

```
#ifndef RCPP_TEST_TEST_H
#define RCPP_TEST_TEST_H

#include <limits>
#include <cstdio>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>

namespace rcpptest {
    class Test {
    public:
        static unsigned int test();
    };
}

#endif //RCPP_TEST_TEST_H
```

implementation of test.h in test.cpp:

```
#include "test.h"

namespace rcpptest {
    unsigned int Test::test() {
        omp_set_num_threads(8);
        unsigned int x = 0;

        std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

#pragma omp parallel for
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i) {

#pragma omp critical
            ++x;
        }
        std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        std::cout << "finished (ms): " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - begin).count() <<std::endl;

        return x;
    }
}
```

and main as:

```
#include "src/test.h"

int main() {
    unsigned int x = rcpptest::Test::test();
    return 0;
}
```

If I build and run this program in IDE (CLion) everything works as excepted.

Then I created an R package using Rcpp:

```
library(Rcpp)
Rcpp.package.skeleton('rcppTestLib')
```

and used the SAME C++ source codes for the package + "Rcpp" file to export my test function to be usable from R (rcppTestLib.cpp):

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include "test.h"

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void rcppTest() {
    rcpptest::Test::test();
}
```

If I then run the test from R using the package

```
library(rcppTestLib)
rcppTest()
```

the execution is much slower.

I ran few test using both compiled c++ and Rcpp package and results are:

```
   program   | execution time
-----------------------------
compiled c++ | ~7 200ms
Rcpp package | ~551 000 ms
```

The difference is that using Rcpp package, 8 threads are spawned but each one of them is using only ~1% of CPU while using compiled C++ the 8 threads combined used all of the CPU power.

I tried switching `#pragma omp critical` for `#pragma omp atomic` with results:

```
   program   | execution time
-----------------------------
compiled c++ | ~2 900ms
Rcpp package | ~3 300 ms
```

Using `#pragma omp atomic` Rcpp package spawns 8 threads and uses all of the CPU power. However there is still difference in execution times but not that significant.

So my question is: Why with `#pragma omp critical` R / Rcpp package does not use all the CPU power while with `#pragma omp atomic` it does even tho the same code built and run in CLion uses all CPU power in BOTH cases?

What am I missing here?

Comment: I didn't set it explicitly as it should use number of threads based on number of cores if not specified If I'm not mistaken. I added it (see edited test.cpp and test.h) but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two possible options here:

1. In package form, the `OpenMP` flag options were not yet set in `src/Makevars` (unix) or `src/Makevars.win` (windows)
2. Missing `num_threads(x)` as `critical` rolls out

---

For one, place in the `src/Makevars` or `src/Makevars.win` file:

```
PKG_LIBS = $(LAPACK_LIBS) $(BLAS_LIBS) $(FLIBS) $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CFLAGS)
PKG_CFLAGS = $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CFLAGS)
PKG_CXXFLAGS = $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS)
```

For details, see: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#OpenMP-support

---

Regarding a missing `num_threads(x)`... I've been able to speed up the problem a bit...

Changing:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
```

to

```
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(4)
```

Yields:

**Before**

```
finished (ms): 30822
[1] 1e+08
```

vs.

**After**

```
finished (ms): 17979
[1] 1e+08
```

or about a 1.7 speedup. My thought is somewhere in `cmake` a global thread option is being set.

```
omp_set_num_threads(x)
```

or

```
set OMP_NUM_THREADS=x
```

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libgomp/omp_005fset_005fnum_005fthreads.html

https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-linux-developer-guide-setting-the-number-of-threads-using-an-openmp-environment-variable

Comment: I used the `Makevars` you suggested and the output of building the Rccp package files looks something like this:
`E:/Programs/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++  -I"e:/Programs/R/R-3.4.2/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"e:/Programs/R/R-3.4.2/library/Rcpp/include"     -fopenmp   -O3 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c test.cpp -o test.o`

Used `#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(4)` but the problem persists. 4 threads are spawned but each uses only ~2% of CPU.

Answer (score 2):

@coatless is once again entirely correct. The *default* `src/Makevars*` we create has no OpenMP.  You see this on a current enough compiler:

```
ccache g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include"    -fpic  -g -O3 -Wall -pipe   -march=native -c test.cpp -o test.o
test.cpp:10:0: warning: ignoring #pragma omp parallel [-Wunknown-pragmas]
 #pragma omp parallel for

test.cpp:13:0: warning: ignoring #pragma omp critical [-Wunknown-pragmas]
 #pragma omp critical
```

Once you add the `src/Makevars` as needed, all is good. `htop` shows as many CPUs as I chose to be pegged.

But your example is still bad because the loop does too little. The overhead becomes dominant.  I have multitple cores here but there is not reason it should run faster with `OMP_NUM_THREADS=2` should run faster that `OMP_NUM_THREADS=3` or `OMP_NUM_THREADS=4` -- apart from the fact
that we seem to have nothing but overhead here.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer! I had OpenMP support in my Makevars.win, otherwise as you pointed out I wouldn't even be able to build the Rcpp package.

You are right, the example is bad considering the parallelisation but I wanted to make the smallest program to reproduce the behaviour.

I've been digging around some more and tried my example on Linux server and it seem to work just fine in Rcpp package. I suspect it probably is non-Rcpp problem.

Comment: There are several good posts about OpenMP at the [Rcpp Gallery](http://gallery.rcpp.org/tags/openmp/).